# git archive from changed files on bare repos

Tags: git, diff, archive

I have a remote bare repository (no working dir) that creates install-tars. Works nice. But now I want to create tars only of the changed files. I tried it this way:

```
git archive --format=tar --prefix='/' HEAD `git diff V1.02 --name-only` | gzip -9 > ~/tars/update-v1.02-`git describe master --tags`.tar.gz
```

This works great with my local repository. It creates a tar with the files from tagged version V1.02 to the latest commit. But it doesn't work with bare reposities. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two commit form of `git diff` will work in a bare repository (`git diff [options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]`).

The following should do what I understand you want:

```
git archive --format=tar --prefix='/' master `git diff V1.02 master --name-only` | gzip -9 > ~/tars/update-v1.02-`git describe master --tags`.tar.gz
```

I also suggest changing the `HEAD` from your original command to `master` (as shown above) to be consistent with the rest of the command, and be resilient if someone changes which branch `HEAD` points to (alternatively replacing all occurrences of `master` with `HEAD` in the example above).

Comment: Hey Jacob, thanks for your reply. Too bad that I didn't get a notification from stackoverflow.

Comment: When I try your command, git gives me the following:
`fatal: ambiguous argument 'V1.02': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions`

Where do ich have to put the '--'? 

` git archive --format=tar --prefix='/' master `git diff V1.02 -- master --name-only` | gzip -9 > ../tar.tar.gz

fatal: bad revision 'V1.02'`

Comment: `--`, if used at all, goes after all non-path options.  In your example, you wouldn't use it at all since you're not using any form of path limiting with `git diff`.

Comment: Jacob... errr... forget what I said. The error-Message showed up because I didn't pushed the tags.

Your answer was 100% correct, it works perfect. Many thanks.