# How to simple CI/CD with git bare repo

Tags: git, cicd, git-bare

In Office, we use git bare repo to be our remote repo on NAS, we don't use gitlab or github etc.

And we have another own remote server to host products(without git). I need to FTP to remote server and deploy manually everytime.

At least, I want to FTP to remote server automaticlly after I push to remote bare repo specific branch or after switch to another commit in remote bare repo,

At first, I intend to use git hooks(after recive or post checkout) to FTP to remote server, but I don't know how to do it in "remote bare repo to another remote server", Or does any other tools I can use  with bare repo?

Comment: You could switch to GitLab or GitHub pretty seamlessly. Is there a reason you don't? It seems like a waste of time to try to cobble together a poor man's Git server.

Comment: if using external git service like gitlab/github/bitbucket is out of the question (e.g.: organization policy), you can also use on prem deployable / open source git service like gitea (they can be integrated with a runner)

Comment: `does any other tools I can use with bare repo?` Screwdriver, Jenkins, CircleCI, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to do it in "remote bare repo to another remote server"

As long as that remote bare repo can access (network) the other remote server, its [`post-receive` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks) can be configured to execute any command you need.
Including an sftp or an scp, in order to copy an archive of the bare repository content (through [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive), even for [just the changed files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12928036/6309))

No need for CICD then: a simple push to the remote bare repository would trigger the hook.